# general term of taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have a taylor series (in this case maclaurin as its at 0) for $(x+1)^\frac23$ and have found the first 5 terms, however, I'm unsure how to find the general term.

$f(x) = (x+1)^\frac23$
$\;f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}(x+1)^\frac{-1}{3}$
$\;f''(x) = \frac{-2}{9}(x+1)^\frac{-4}{3}$
$\;f'''(x) = \frac{8}{27}(x+1)^\frac{-7}{3}$
$\;f''''(x) = \frac{-56}{81}(x+1)^\frac{-10}{3}$

At the moment I have from n = 0, $\frac{-1^{?}}{(n+1)!}(1^{\frac{2}{3}-n})(\frac{??}{3^{n+1}})$

(?) The sequence for the -1 seems to be: 1,1,-1,1,-1 but I am unable to find a pattern.

(??) The other sequence seems to go: $\frac 23, \frac{2}{9}, \frac{8}{27}, \frac{56}{81}$
I can see the denominator pattern appears to be $3^{n+1}$ but I can't find the pattern for the numerator. I ignored the negatives as I assume the $(-1)^n$ will cover that.

Comment: The generalized binomial formula may interest you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Thank you, I had completely forgotten about binomial expansion

Comment: Also is the general term the nth term or is it the sum up to any term?

Comment: I think it’s the nth term

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation follows the pattern

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{a_n}{3^n}(x+1)^{2/3-n} \tag 1 $$

for $n\geqslant 1$ and with $a_n\in\Bbb N$.  To find $a_n$, derive $(1)$:

$$\begin{align}
f^{(n+1)}(x) &= (-1)^{n+1}\frac{a_n}{3^n}\left(\frac23-n\right)(x+1)^{2/3-(n+1)} \\
&= (-1)^{n+2}\frac{(3n-2)a_n}{3^{n+1}} (x+1)^{2/3-(n+1)}\\\tag 2
\end{align}$$

This gives a recursive definition for $a_n$:

$$ a_{n+1} = (3n-2)a_n \ ,\qquad a_1 = 2 $$

which is $$\begin{align}
2&,\\ 2&,\\ 8&=2\cdot 4,\\ 56&=8\cdot 7,\\ 560&=56\cdot 10,\\ &\ \vdots
\end{align}$$

Notice the pattern even works for $n=0$ with $a_0=-1, a_1 = (-2)\cdot(-1)=2$.

Using the notation of [multi-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations), we can write for $n\geqslant0$:

$$a_{n+1} = 2\cdot(3n-2)!_{(3)}$$